# updating the table in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, jsp

I am trying the following code.

```
String sym=request.getParameter("symbol");
Statement st1=con.createStatement();
String symIns="UPDATE "+tblname+" SET Symbol='+sym+'";
int m=st1.executeUpdate(symIns);
if(m==0)
    out.println("m is zero");
else 
if(m!=0)
    out.println("Inserted");
```

I am receiving the values of sym and tblname from previous page.But After executing this code it is printing m as zero and hence not updating the table. This code is not working for the table which does not have any record(contain only null values). But working for the table which have some records in it. I have also tried to execute it directly in the database. It is showing `query executed successfully` , but giving message as `(0 row(s) affected)`. This is the query which is successfully running in the database.`

> UPDATE six SET SYMBOL='eq' WHERE SYMBOL='be';

As I said it is working for this table and this table is having value for SYMBOL column as 'be'.

Comment: A lot of questions: Do you have any errors/warning? Other queries works? `tblname` exists in database? Are there any records in `tblname` table? Your DB connection doesn't need explicit `COMMIT`?

Comment: This is wide open for sql injections. You might have to consider a alternative solution

Comment: Try to print String symIns in console,   than execute in datatabase directly.

Comment: @Grzegorz Gierlik: No errors/warnings, Yes other queries are working ex. I tried select query and it is working. And tblname is also there in the database. Yes there records in the tblname.

Comment: @ NoRules:After executing query in database it is showing query executed successfully but is also giving (0 row(s) affected) message

Comment: Hi,
As per your comments

I can say that there is no problem with your code. ExecuteUpdate returns number of rows updated in database.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Ok. I got the problem. I have tried this code for both the tables. The table which contain records, and the table which does not have records(and contains null value).It is working for the tables which already have some records in it. But not for the ones which does not have records(and contains null value). So is there any way to replace those null values with these values?

Comment: `UPDATE tableName SET fieldName=myVal` should work though it has NULL value in rows. Make sure NULL is not getting pass in parameters

Comment: @ Hardik Mishra: I have tried to print the parameters and those are displayed on the console.

Comment: Actually I am not getting why it is showing query executed successfully and giving (0 row(s) affected) message when I am trying to execute it in database

Comment: Edit your post and provide more code snippet and test values.Do not over use Comments. They are just to clarify.

Comment: Post the query which you directly run in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is behaving correctly. If you have matching records, it will update the rows.

So, In your query  `UPDATE six SET SYMBOL='eq' WHERE SYMBOL='be';`, It will update the `six` table where you have rows with field value  'be'. But It will not update where you have NULL.

The query will execute but does not update any records and thus returns zero rows affected.

So, If you want to update rows which contains `NULL` as field value.

Add `IS NULL`

`UPDATE six SET SYMBOL='eq' WHERE SYMBOL IS NULL`

Comment: Tried that as well , still it is showing the same message : (0 row(s) affected) and Query executed successfully.

Comment: It means the table does not contains null values in `SYMBOL` field. I am not getting what you want to do ?

Comment: Actually I am creating a new table. It is now showing null values for all fields. I want to update the table and want to set the value as shown in the code.

Comment: @ Hardik: Thank you very much. The same line of code is working now.